# Docker VS Code WSL 2 exception

Tags: .net, docker, visual-studio-code, installation

I recently added the Docker extension onto VS code. Then I downloaded Docker, after installation I received this exception:

```
.NET Framework Error- Unhandled exception- exception type 'Docker.ApiServices.WSL2.WslKernel`
```

I'm not quite sure where to proceed from here.

[image: Microsoft .Net Framework Error]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same exception and command:
`wsl --set-default-version 2`
returned message:
`An update to the WSL 2 kernel component is required. For information, visit the https://aka.ms/wsl2kernel website.` (This is not original message, I've translated it from my native language.)
When I've followed link and installed kernel update docker starts working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Docker is trying to run on Windows WSL framework/feature.
Please make sure you've turned it on.

How to do that?

1. In windows search type - **turn windows features on or off**
2. Make sure you've the option - **Windows subsystem for Linux** selected there, if it isn't, select it and click okay.
   [image: windows subsystem image addedd]
3. It'll install WSL on your system & tell you to restart, after system restart your docker will run properly!
4. As a bonus, run powershell with administrative privileges & run this command `wsl --set-default-version 2`, this will make your system switch to latest version of WSL with added benefits.

If this answer helps, let me know, or I can go in further details.